# akka cluster Connection refused: address is now > gated for [5000] ms

Tags: scala, akka

I have a cluster with 2 workers and 1 master. the cluster is implemented with Akka and Scala.

When i killed the worker and try to run it again with the following command:

> java -Xms3500M -Xmx3500M -Dlog_file_name=worker1
>   "-Dconfig.file=F:\cluster\application.conf" -cp cluster.jar
>   knowmail.Worker worker1 2551

I get the following error:

> Connection refused
>   Association with remote system
>   [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@xxxxxx:2552] has failed, address is now
>   gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [As
>   kka.tcp://ClusterSystem@xxxx:2552]] Caused by: [Connection
>   refused: no further information: /xxxx:2552]

a configuration of cluster:

```
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    log-received-messages = on
    log-sent-messages = on

    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "xxxxxx"
      port = 8888
      bind-hostname = 0.0.0.0
      bind-port = 8888
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@xxxxx:2551",
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@xxxxxx:2552"]

    auto-down-unreachable-after = 20s
  }

  http.client.parsing.max-content-length = infinite
}
```

Did anyone encountered this error and solved it?

Comment: are you running any firewall software on this machine? could you check if these ports are open?

Comment: no firewall ...

Comment: Could you add your config file?

Comment: So you are running your nodes on .6:2551, .8:8888 and .10:2552?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when I start one of the seed nodes/workers before the other seed node has been started.

So one seed node is looking for the other and reports the following error of:

> akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.5.2.10:2552] has failed, address is now
>   gated for [5000] ms.